# Properties of a continuous function $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]$

Tags: calculus

Consider any continuous function $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]$. Which one of following statement is incorrect?

1. $f$ always has atleast one maximum in interval $[0,1]$
2. $f$ always has atleast one minimum in interval $[0,1]$
3. There exist $x \in[0,1]$ so that $f (x)=x$
4. Function $f$ must always have property that $f(0) \in \{0,1\}, f(1)\in\{0,1\}$ and $f (0) + f (1)=1$.

My doubt: I can't recall what specific property do continuous function have which applies to this question. I need some suggestions. Thanks

Comment: Do you have any ideas? Is there at least one statement for which you are sure it is correct? Did you try to find a counterexample for any of the statements?

Comment: To think about 3, try to draw a picture.

Comment: Consider the mean value theorem on the function $g(x)=x-f(x)$

Comment: Moreover, what can you say about continuous on compact intervals ($[0,1]$ in this case)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

1. No matter what book you are learning from, I am 100 percent sure that there was at least one theorem or statement or something saying something about maximums of functions on closed intervals. Look it up!
2. See my hint for 1.
3. Take a look at the function $g(x) = f(x) - x$ and the intermediate value theorem.
4. Think of the simplest functions you possibly can: constants. Do all constant functions satisfy property 4?

Comment: A countinous fxn in bounded interval, achieves maximum and minimum. Makes 1 ,2 true. 3 is true but its not getting clear

Comment: @singularity What can you say about the function $g(x)=f(x)-x$? What is its value at $0$? What is its value at $1$? What does the intermediate value theorem say?

Comment: its not given what f (x) is at x= 0 and 1

Comment: @singularity True. But again, what does the intermediate value theorem say?

Comment: for any c between f (0) and f (1) there is some x,st f (x)=c

Comment: @singularity Correct. And how can you use this theorem to prove that a function takes the value $0$?